# Transaction invoking another transaction in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I was wondering if transaction can invoke another transaction since I'm standing in front of a problem:

I'm trying to implement a **double auction** where producers of energy and consumers of energy can commit `bids` (buy certain amount of energy at certain price) and `asks` (offer certain amount of energy at certain price). 
The auction is supposed to clear the market every X minutes and I'm currently wondering how the `clear_market` transaction is to be evoked. Ideally, there is no central authority calling it when it's time, but some code executing itself automatically "on-chain" after the auction time has elapsed.
However, I currently don't see how to implement it.

My initial idea was that when a participant commits a `bid` oder `ask` transaction, it would fist check if there is a new auction period, and if yes, invoke the `clear_market` transaction for the previous auction period. But the way I understand the transaction execution, if a transaction is executed inside another transaction, the invoked transaction will not show up in the transaction registry. However, it would be good to have a trace of that transaction, since it returns the market clearing price and updates coin balances of the producers/consumers.

Do you see a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

how deep are you already in the fabric topic? It seems like you confuse transactions with chaincode. Transactions are the product of invoked chaincode which alters the state of the ledger bundleded by orderer into blocks.

Back to your question: Basically it is possible to let chaincode call another chaincode (when it's on the same channel) but it is not recommended. What i would suggest for you is having a look at emitting and subscribing events. Hopefully this serves your problem!

Comment: thanks for your answer! Since the Composer modeling language uses the term `transaction` I simply adopted it. But you are right, I was wondering whether chaincode can call another chaincode. Why is it not recommended?

I know about events, I was just hoping to find an elegant way for my `clear_market` chaincode to be automatically executed every X minutes.

Comment: Not recommended was maybe a bit exaggerated. I was in the same situation wanting to react on sth when a certain function from chaincode is invoked. After finding out about event emitting on chain and subscribing to them off chain it was the perfect fit to handle and automate things easier in terms of overview and user identification. There is a dedicated function `InvokeChaincode`for doing what you asked for but not knowing exact use case i dont know whether this serves your purpose in the end. I just can recommend to you having a look at handling events and think through your use case again

Comment: Ok, thanks ... I will do that and maybe I'll find a better way of handling things.